# Laravel 5 request value null

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5, request

This is code in my controller:

```
  public function postExample(Request $request) {

         $id = $request->input('subjectId');
         Log::warning('id is:' . $id . ",and request:" . $request);
```

The thing is that variable $id is null (empty string). Here is log:

```
 id is:,and request:POST      ....
 Accept:          application/json, text/plain, */*
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Content-Length:  19
 Content-Type:    application/x-www-form-urlencoded

         . . . .

 {"subjectId":"13"}
```

I tried with:`$id = $request->get('subjectId');` and its the same.

EDIT: I'm using angularjs for post, this is the code:

```
            $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/profesor/setStrukturaPredmeta',
            data:  { subjectId: '13' },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $("body").html(JSON.stringify(response));
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $("body").html("error: "+JSON.stringify(response));

            });
```

Comment: how do you define your route?

Comment: @PeteHouston Did you mean route in my routes.php file? I can edit post if that is what u mean? I didn't thought that its relevant, since the data in Response object contains the data I want, and I'm sure that client side call is hitting my function cause the log file is being updated.

Comment: it is related, anyway; just remove the prefix `post` on `postExample`, it is preserved for implicit route

Comment: @PeteHouston I didn't know that, but that's not the issue, cause I was translating my code from my native language for this post, and it was called something else, but I had word "set" in it. I edited.

Comment: @craig_h I edited my question.

Comment: can't help if you don't share the **exact** piece of your code when you say everything you do seems to be **normal**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing headers in my angularjs controller, but I dont understand why it doesn't work when they are included.

Comment: Yeah, same problem... Idk why is this working, lol!